# Parse JSON with jQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, json.net

I'm trying to parse this JSON string:

```
{"946cb446-cee6-488d-9f2c-0088e173975d":"/slide7.jpg",
"d120b1c9-58d2-4eb6-94ec-052cf6323dea":"/slide24.jpg",
"2da5187c-1bc2-4bc6-a4f0-0d2cf1be3689":"/slide21.jpg",
"299002c3-22f8-4428-8f38-1310b58ac113":"/slide26.jpg",
"ec46f5ad-7a42-4ebc-935a-16a4f4adcfe3":"/slide27.jpg",
"4bccd0b8-b684-4861-93b3-17759893a1cd":"/slide44.jpg",
"3d430596-04ff-4103-9a70-300ed992bd5c":"/slide14.jpg",
"ba9f4550-8844-4733-b3cb-31a6a57efc7d":"/slide45.jpg",
"994e49f7-6346-46a3-a6ee-322789fc0142":"/slide6.jpg",
"be1f5e2e-4ac6-4f6b-aae2-3af212de1d09":"/slide30.jpg",
"094c304d-1afb-409e-aa3e-3bfb050e5eaf":"/slide40.jpg",
"2cf38f65-9587-4d21-96c0-3e093f8017eb":"/slide3.jpg",
"813a470f-807a-41e3-8ad9-3e0fb8f043ee":"/slide16.jpg",
"1e7c1d9b-0adc-42f1-a1cc-3f9279d9faa1":"/slide31.jpg",
"36f62a81-d360-4892-82be-5121b0bcf137":"/slide39.jpg",
"4218f4c7-3997-4266-bcc2-58659cf43fab":"/slide1.jpg",
"248c8fbc-7be5-4531-89bb-5aaf25017667":"/slide2.jpg",
"645e7869-68d5-4e61-ad6b-5c2aafb455a5":"/slide8.jpg",
"c541462d-51eb-473a-aa2f-5c30ed2c3e89":"/slide13.jpg",
"02a2b45a-56a6-4e39-80f9-6c9c300bf19d":"/slide18.jpg",
"1e9ce967-c923-425b-b048-6f4a5738b05f":"/slide32.jpg",
"4e86ed21-472e-4916-9a54-73158a1891e3":"/slide23.jpg",
"90a646a8-5d9c-42e2-916c-7439630f4cda":"/slide22.jpg",
"e9fbd50c-a470-4420-b0c8-747c810587d7":"/slide5.jpg",
"d5181fd2-4e5e-4866-a76a-74c9f97d6090":"/slide46.jpg",
"2355c1b9-a484-40cb-9040-7c9db3737019":"/slide9.jpg",
"22b2d09e-0abb-46d2-a503-9c54e9a953fa":"/slide37.jpg",
"eae0ca42-f873-4508-a228-a94b5e9b7454":"/slide42.jpg",
"9fc385ae-ecc1-41ce-bfd1-b1e9f5e8cd34":"/slide11.jpg",
"040e95af-3e28-421d-b975-b5ab3c267c6e":"/slide20.jpg",
"cb3d0743-ec2f-4a63-9a26-c978c19851c4":"/slide15.jpg",
"b019f69d-de71-4f7f-9d44-c9d6185e4966":"/slide38.jpg",
"085fdd67-2e32-4f09-a93b-cf1ba81fd4a3":"/slide33.jpg",
"099bb24f-489f-40ab-aa4e-d3c5c499cbee":"/slide28.jpg",
"ff4f04ef-a114-4cce-9f91-d5b129f86d80":"/slide41.jpg",
"b9e8c44f-b838-4bb7-8e06-d9b38e24a6e2":"/slide35.jpg",
"e9785a7e-0673-40dc-a8c8-e25e01ca39e3":"/slide4.jpg",
"5519594f-5f99-4681-b2f9-e2c49b56d838":"/slide25.jpg",
"082dcb2f-8396-42a8-a83e-e478c90e1059":"/slide10.jpg",
"93647403-b429-4e68-9d8a-ea7cf7e0ff35":"/slide36.jpg",
"7d79f12a-9649-46f8-867c-ebffa2fc2adb":"/slide17.jpg",
"1be6980a-8a75-449f-af59-efec739a0177":"/slide34.jpg",
"457538fa-87b9-4fb2-bf80-fa63278bd0eb":"/slide19.jpg",
"20499f07-da0f-4e6e-9c44-faf74f737644":"/slide43.jpg",
"01815f25-7dab-4bf7-aede-fd074128332c":"/slide12.jpg",
"7c913e57-65ae-458a-a8c0-fd2c9c17b813":"/slide29.jpg"}
```

with this:

```
success: function (msg) {
   var arr = msg.d;

   // Replace the div's content with the page
   $.each(arr, function (index, element) {
      var text = "<li>" + element + "</li>";
      var newli = $(text);

   $("#listPages").append(text);
});
```

and I'm getting the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '53' in {"946cb446-cee6-488d-9f2c-0088e173975d":"/slide7.jpg"}**

Some Help??

Comment: Please indent the json line to a more readable format.

Comment: Why are there quotes around the brackets? How are you generating this JSON?

Comment: Your JSON structure is an array of strings. The content of the strings looks like it's intended to be objects. The strings contain unescaped double quotes. Short version, your JSON isn't valid. How is the JSON being created?

Comment: @Hugo Pedrosa :- Did you get the solution? If no, then can you please let me know why `msg.d` ? what does this `d` stands for? Secondly, `var arr = msg;` should be only this. Please give some detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your response data is simple string - so you have to parse it to convert in data object, or parse in callback function

```
success: function (msg) {
  JSON.parse(msg.d, function (key, value) {
    var text = "<li>" + value+ "</li>";
    var newli = $(text);
    $("#listPages").append(text);
  }
});
```

Here is additional info
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace - with & #8211; without the space after the &